# Convert list of unicode list in list

Tags: python, string, list, unicode

I am facing a problem.

In Python, I have a list. This list is a list of lists. But the lists are unicode ones, so it appears like strings.

Indeed, I have something like this :

```
[u'[7,6,5,4,3, 1]', u'[.......]', ...]
```

Do you know a simple way to convert it to

```
[[...],[...], ...] ?
```

I tried by processing the strings, but it is not an easy way...

Thank you for your help! :-)

Comment: Are they valid Python literals? If so, then just use `ast.literal_eval` and safely evaluate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ast.literal_eval` with `map` or a list comprehension:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> lis = [u'[7,6,5,4,3, 1]', u'[4, 5, 6]']
>>> map(literal_eval, lis)
[[7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 1], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> [literal_eval(x) for x in lis]
[[7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 1], [4, 5, 6]]
```